# How to Disable SSL on ASP.NET Core API 3.1 Project in Visual Studio 2019 16.8.3 Build?

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

How will you disable SSL if you already set it up when you create your project to not use it on the first place? If I will try to create a new ASP.NET API 3.1 project without SSL, it will work fine when you first run it.

But on my case, I want to run it using

> Project

setting under Debug -> Launch option:

[image]

Under this option, the typical option you usually see like check or uncheck SSL is missing so I am not able to disable it. So when you run this API template, you will prompt by the usual "Trust SSL Certificate" dialog box.

On the first place, I already disable SSL when I create my project, that's why it is strange to see this dialog box.

[image]

But when I changed the settings back to

> IIS Express

under Debug -> Launch option, it was already been disabled, and when I run it, it runs fine without any issue about SSL notification. Is this an issue on `Project` option only?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In `Startup.cs` try removing

```
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: Unfortunately there was no line on my code to comment it out as you specified on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the dialog box, if your project launch set to 'project' and you don't want to see that dialog box, you just need to enter your application URL in the button input box with HTTP protocol.

the default app URL is Https://loclahost:5001 or Https://localhost:5000 that you can be changed to any other URL such as http://localhost:27510

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work unfortunately. The pop-up still appears. I entered the URL on App URL textbox but the pop-up still continues.

Comment: The entered URL must be HTTP. something like this  http://localhost:27510

Answer (score 2):

In `Startup.cs` try removing

```
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

And in `launchsettings.json`:

```
"useSSL": false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).