# How to disable SSL on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I was trying to deploy my web app without using HTTPs using a custom domain:

[image]

But all the settings I made did not work, when I enter the url I still get the https version.

Reference: [How to Disable SSL on ASP.NET Core API 3.1 Project in Visual Studio 2019 16.8.3 Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65443316/how-to-disable-ssl-on-asp-net-core-api-3-1-project-in-visual-studio-2019-16-8-3)

Comment: Open a privacy mode tab and type the full URL with `http://` prefix, which prevents the browser from sticking to HTTPS.

Comment: Works. How can I disable the cache, that people who know the site wont get prompted by the unsecure ssl warning?

Comment: You cannot suppress that unsecure warning unless you have a valid server certificate and HTTPS in place. That's de facto for HTTP connections today.

Comment: I was looking for something like this: https://www.how2code.info/en/blog/website_dynamic_cache-and-website_local_cache_option/ . But this does not really work, entereing the URL will still forward to the https version ?

Answer (score 0):

> entering the URL will still forward to the https version

You  can't disable the HTTPS scheme on an Azure website, that's one thing configured centrally and not something you have the ability to turn on or off.

You can  simply load a free SSL certificate onto the site that's valid for your own domain .
Please refer  [How to load a free SSL certificate into an Azure website](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/09/the-complete-guide-to-loading-free-ssl.html).

**NOTE:**-

> you can only load your own certificate on Basic and Standard Azure
> websites, you won't be able to do this if you're on Free or Shared.

For more information please refer the below link :-

. [MAP custom domain| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=cname) .

. Similar [SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092438/how-to-remove-azure-ssl-binding) .